# JMeter - execute QUIC request

Tags: java, jmeter, jsr223, quic

There are options to call TCP,HTTP2 and UDP request in JMeter,

But is there a way to call [QUIC](https://www.chromium.org/quic) request in JMeter

> QUIC is a new transport which reduces latency compared to that of TCP. On the surface, QUIC is very similar to TCP+TLS+HTTP/2 implemented on UDP. Because TCP is implemented in operating system kernels, and middlebox firmware, making significant changes to TCP is next to impossible. However, since QUIC is built on top of UDP, it suffers from no such limitations.

I found [kwik](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/kwik/src/master/) which is java client, but for HTTP3 (and not for production use)

> Kwik is a client implementation of the QUIC protocol in Java.
>
> Kwik can be used to transport HTTP3, but it is not a HTTP3 client. If you're looking for a HTTP3 client, check out Flupke.
>
> Kwik is not yet suitable for production use.

I found also [JQUIC](https://github.com/hrqiang/quic-java) but I don't find in it any relevant **Java code**

Comment: From the phrase "but for HTTP3", it seems you think that kwik can only be used in combination with HTTP3. This is not the case: you can use kwik (as a Java QUIC library) to setup and use QUIC connections (of course, to do something useful, you'd need a protocol on top of it, just as is the case with TCP). You could use kwik to write a JMeter QUIC plugin, it wouldn't even be hard i think. Contact me (i'm the author of kwik) if you want to try and need support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no plugin that provides QUIC request sampler for JMeter. You would probably have to [write one](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html).

There is [HTTP2 Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin) so maybe the guys in BlazeMeter will write one for QUIC one day.

Comment: I found JQUIC, but I don't find any relevant java code https://github.com/hrqiang/quic-java